# Chrome doesn't render properly a page. It works perfectly in Firefox/IE

Tags: css, google-chrome, dojo, webkit, cross-browser

I'm having a problem with the layout of a page in Google Chrome (version 27.0.1453.110). This layout works perfectly in Firefox (21) and even in Internet Explorer (9), but not in Chrome. Basically it consists in three big divs that are supposed to be stacked, but they are overlapped

The problem it's only visible the first time that the page is shown. When I resize the screen or open the web tool of Chrome (the equivalent of firebug, hitting F12) it renders the layout properly. Not so when I press ctrl+f5 or f5. In this case it returns to the incorrect layout.

I have tried it in Safari as well, in order to discard a Webkit issue, but the layout is messed up in the same way, so it makes me think that is not an issue related to Chrome, but to Webkit.

I'm using Dojo (version 1.8). Discarded the version of Dojo, because I have tried with the latest one (1.9) with exactly the same result. I have achieved the opposite effect with dojo.style, modifying the css dynamically. When I say the opposite, I mean that I can get it showing good the first time, but not in the refresh. Of course it's not a solution...

Anyone knows about a bug in Chrome or Webkit, or possible fix (even a hack) to this? I have seen not very useful information about it. It is becoming painful, and any help would be very useful. Thanks!

Comment: So...what's the problem?

Comment: Did u tried to find out if the elements were loaded in the HTML tree?  Using developer tools would be handy.

Comment: Gaynorvader, I have edited the first paragraph. Now the problem is clearer I think

Comment: Edorka, the elements are completely loaded. he problem is with the displaying

Comment: Could you post the code to the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your html structure. Perhaps one of div's are not close